# How to find an application on google play if you are an internal tester

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, publishing

I have uploaded my application to the google play store for internal testing. It's providing me a link for internal testers. On opening the link it's showing me the app not found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YOH1.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can not find a directly internal release app in the google play store.
There is one URL in the google play store account after your internal release of the app.

And that URL only can be accessed for whom you add as an internal tester.

Comment: Hi there, I tried the same but it isn't working out.